# Linking .dll files to .exe file

Tags: c++

I have just created my first graphical application with the GTK library and I have a little problem.
The application only opens a window of type GtkWidget and shows it to the user as a test.
When compiling this application with Linux g ++, the application opens correctly.
When compiling this application with MinGW g ++ for Windows, this shows that several .dlls are needed to run.
The only solution I have found is to save the .dll files in the same application folder, but I would like to save the .dll files in a separate folder for a better project structure.
I have built the application using the Visual Studio Code text editor.
The compilation has been done using MinGW (and I would like to keep it that way)

Comment: [DLL Search Order for Desktop Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications)

Comment: That is basically how it works in Windows. Either your installer makes sure that the MinGW DLLs appear in the system DLL directories, or you place them with the EXE in your applications bin folder.

Comment: I know that you can put all DLLs on the EXE directory, but I'd like to know if there is a possibility to put them in other folder

Comment: Putting them in the same directory is the standard, everybody does that. Unsure what's the problem with project structure.

Comment: @SourceCreator the page linked in the first comment has information to get it to work in multiple ways. You can use a thin wrapper exe that pretty much just calls `SetDllDirectory` and then compile the rest of your code into a DLL, load one entry point of that dll, which will then load all its dependencies with the search path. Or you can use two *.exe files, one being essentially a launcher that sets up the working directory and starts the other.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way to do it, which is why almost all Windows applications just put the DLLs in the same directory as the executable.  Modifying the PATH variable for the user is kind of intrusive (and might be undone by the user).